# The same CSS in different files makes the page load differently

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a file called global.css and I moved some css there as I was using it across more than one page, then I proceeded to remove the css from a page specific stylesheet and the styling for the page broke down. If I put the css back where it was I get the same style again.

Here is the code:

```
.thumb {
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
width:  24.66666666vw;
height: 24.66666666vw;
max-width: 500px;
max-height: 500px;
margin: 1vw;
}

.photoGrid {
    width: 80vw;
    height: auto;
    margin: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: space-between;
}
```

P.S. the photoGrid is a div and there are multiple thumb divs inside.

P.P.S.
I think it was because I called the flex box to be a column later but it was supposed to be for a different media query, it seems fine now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess, I would say its a issue with the order of loading the DOM and its elements. You probably have different styles taking over from other stylesheets. Chrome's inspector tool can help you see what styles are loading first and taking priority.

Answer (score 3):

It is about order of the styles, styles imported later override ones earlier. Sounds like you have conflicting styles. Getting the order right might fix this issue, it may also cause problems else where.